# msvcr110.dll is missing although Visual C++ Redistributable package is installed?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have a .NET application installed on the machine of a client which uses Tesseract.NET. He gets the following behavior:

At startup, these message boxes appear a couple of times:

[image: msvcrmissingmsg]

[image: libleptmissing]

My error log shows:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'
>   occurred in Skillconomy.Buddy.exe
>
> Additional information: The type initializer for 'xyz' threw an
>   exception. A first chance exception of type
>   'Tesseract.LoadLibraryException' occurred in Tesseract.dll
>   MyProgram.vshost.exe Error: 0 : Failed to find dll "libtesseract302",
>   for processor architecture x86. A first chance exception of type
>   'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in Tesseract.dll

I know that msvcr110.dll is the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 which can be installed using a package: [MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30679). That is why I asked my customer to install the package prior to installing my software. I cannot be entirely sure though, that he did.

I have tried to reproduce the issue my customer describes on my own machine. First, I uninstalled all VC++ Runtime Redistributable Packages that I had installed on my development machine:

[image: msvcr]

No effect, everything still working fine on my machine.

I have then removed the following files:

- C:/Windows/System32/msvcr110.dll
- C:/Windows/SysWOW64/msvcr110.dll

**The issue is reproduced, I get exactly the same behavior as described by my customer. Note, that the second error message box is also not showing anymore, although I have not added or moved the DLL liblept168.dll.**

So now, after reproducing the issue, I obviously want to fix it again:

I reinstalled the Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Redistributables for Visual Studio 2012 an restarted my machine, but the issue is not fixed, the DLLs which I have deleted before (see above) have not been reinstalled and the issue when starting the program remains.

Manually copying the DLLs which I have deleted before back to the OS directories fixes the issue, but it is not an option to ask the client to manually drag and drop DLLs to OS system folders and it does not seem to be a clean solution anyways.

The way which I have expected to fix the issue - installing the Visual C++ Redistributable - does not have an effect, as it doesn't install the required DLLs in the place I need them. Also, uninstalling the packages on my system did not reproduce the bug, so there seems to be no actual relation between the bug and the package (which is the first thing I don't understand). Secondly, I don't know how to provide a proper fix. So my questions are:

**A. Why is there no relation between the Visual C++ redistributables and the bugs, although obviously the missing DLL (MSVCR110.DLL) is what the redistributable package is all about?**

**B. Why is the missing DLL (MSVCR110.DLL) not installed in the OS folders by the installer package?**

**C. Should MSVCR110.DLL exist in the OS folders anyway and what could be reasons it obviously doesn't on my client's machine?**

**D. How can I provide a fix, that doesn't involve manual copying of DLLs?**

I would be very happy about answers to any of these questions or ideas on how to proceed with the issue. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: You got msvcr110.dll on your machine because you installed Visual Studio.  So did not need the vcredist installer.  Removing it would require uninstalling VS, you of course don't want to go there.  Core issue is that your dev machine just doesn't compare well to the user's machine.  And that you overlooked that your program has a dependency on msvcr110.dll.  Easy mistake but a responsible 3rd party software supplier is never shy about telling you.  Beyond relying on customer complaints, you only flush out problems like this by testing your install on a clean OS, a virtual machine is best.

Comment: Hi Hans, thank you for your answer this is already a step forward. If you like, please post it as an answer, it does answer part of the question really well. I'll pull up a VM and test there. Thank you for the hint, I didn't think about that... That being said, before giving it to the customer, I have tested it on several non development machines, where it all worked well. Bad luck this time... I'll see if I get additional infos from the VM test and let you know :) Thank you!

Comment: @Hans: Still, one more question: If there is no VS installed and then one installs the Redistributable Package, shouldn't this add msvcr110.dll to the OS folders?

Comment: It is very common to accidentally rely on the kindness of another program's installer.  Many of them have a dependency on the Microsoft CRT.  Only a virgin OS install can give you a reliable signal.  Most important conclusion to draw is that you now *know* you have a dependency on msvcr110.dll.  So just make sure it is available, preferably by not relying on vcredist but just copying the DLL yourself into the install directory with your own installer.

Comment: Hi again Hans, I actually was aware of the dependency before and told the customer to install the redistributable package which I thought would be sufficient. I am now starting to wonder whether he maybe didn't do it because I get the impression that installing the package really does place the DLLs in the OS directories where they are expected to be... Maybe I wasn't clear about that in my question.

Comment: Maybe the installer just checks to see if folder exists and doesn't overwrite it. Maybe that would require doing a repair as opposed to an install. Also I'm not a .net expert but doesn't that mean not using strange dependencies?

Comment: Also while explicitly linking is very useful, it can cause conflicts by allowing the application to load a dll dependency from virtually any other directory. So its clear tesseract is loading a library explicitly with LoadLibrary() which means we have no idea where it's supposed to be placed.

Comment: Also between the two application generated messages and the log, it seems you are missing 3 separate dll. I would trust maybe the one system generated error from loadlibrary(). Libtesserac302.dll. Is missing. The others seem to be generated from your own application...

Answer (score 6):

Solution: Needed to install the x86 as well. (my system was x64 so i didn't think I had to).

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I never really fixed the issue but worked around it. Next time, I'll try your solution. Thanks!

Comment: This is correct, the redist needs to be installed to match the architecture (x86 vs x64) of the application that uses it, not the OS.

Comment: Ahhh, life saver! Thanks, man. I was missing that for a game I was trying to run.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old post but it helped me today. I can confirm that in a clean Windows Pro 10 install (x64) installing literally all of the `VCREDIST` (x86 and x64) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same problem while running Windows application in VS 2015, in which I was using a third party dll which was built in VS 2012. When I build third party dll in VS 2015 and used in my application, it solves my problem.